# In AWS, EC2 Instant meta data, is the 'ami-id' replicated to a new instance when it cloned

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When an AMI instance is cloned (snapshot); does its original meta data ami-id copy to the new instance and AMI.  I'd like to know if the original ami-id will be duplicated to all the children and grandchildren images.

Thx,

Answer (score 3):

No.

**AMIs:**

One and only one AMI image will ever have a given AMI ID.

If you copy an AMI image, the new AMI image will have a new AMI ID.

If you create an EC2 instance from an AMI image, then create a new AMI image from that EC2 instance, that too will have a new AMI ID.

There is no built-in "chain" of AMI IDs.

**EC2 Instances:**

One and only one EC2 instance will have a given EC2 instance ID.

If you create EBS snapshots or AMI images from an EC2 instance, and launch a new EC2 instance from that AMI image (or EBS snapshots), then that EC2 instance will have it's own unique EC2 instance ID.

If two EC2 instances are launched from the same AMI image, the metadata for both EC2 instances will indicate the same AMI ID (because both were launched from the same AMI image).

Comment: *There is no built-in "chain" of AMI IDs.* Instance store AMIs had a "chain" concept of an "ancestor AMI," a vestige of which is still present in [instance metadata as `ancestor-ami-ids`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-categories).  Creating an AMI of an EBS-backed instance from the console doesn't seem to populate this.  Not sure if it's possible to build one by hand and include this.  Seems like it would be nice if possible.